# Is there a way to reopen a window after closing it using destroy() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
window6.after(1,lambda:window6.destroy())
```

is what I've been using to close my windows, is there any way to get them back after doing this?
basically, is there something that is the opposite of this?

ps. these are the libraries that I've imported, if it helps in any way

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import ttk
```

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either 

import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the 

whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth 

like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; 

name clashes are the issue.

Comment: also I am pretty sure that there is no way to reverse that method, You could however use say `.withdraw` method if You wanted to "hide" the window and then `.deiconify()` to bring it back

Comment: thank you!<3 I tried using withdraw and deiconify, but there was an error message that said "pyimage3 doesn't exist"?? I wasn't sure how to fix it so I went back to my original code in which I used destroy

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to reopen a window after closing it using destroy() in tkinter?

The short answer is "no". Once it has been destroyed, it is impossible to get back. You should either create the window via a frame or class so that it's easy to recreate, or hide the window by calling `.withdraw()` rather than `.destroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the window code into a class or a function then after destroying it you can create a new instance of it by

1: creating a new instance of the class with the window code in the **init** function

2: call the function the has the code for the window

By doing this you are essentially creating a new instance of the program, but without initiating the script.

```
from tkinter impot *
from tkinter import ttk

#creating window function, not class
def main_window():
    #window code here 
    root = Tk()
    Label(root, text = "Hello World").pack()
    
    #destroying main window
    root.destroy()
    
    root.mainloop()

main_window()
```

Of course, there are a few hurdles such as the window shutting down as soon as it opens, but this is to show that you can create a new instance of a window from your program.

You can wait for user input to see whether or not the window will open or close.

Comment: Also tkinter docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: thank you for your answer<3 I'm still a little confused but I'll try and work it out using this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you took an OOP approach, you can pass a reference to the **Parent Widget** as argument to the **New_Window** and store it in a class attribute.

You´ll have a two way reference: Parent knows child and child knows parent.

Then you can set the **Parent Reference** to the **New_Window** to **None**, from within the child Widget *self.parent.new_window = None* in a close_me() method right after you call self.destroy() on the New_Window:

1st Bonus: this code prevents the opening of more than 1 instance of a Window at a time. You won´t get more than 1 New_Window on the screen. I don´t think having two loggin windows opened or two equal options window makes sense.

2nd Bonus: It is possible to close the window from other parts of the code, as in a MVC patter, the Controller can close the window after doing some processing.

Here´s a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Toolbar(tk.Frame):
    '''Toolbar '''
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # to store the New Window reference
        self.new_window = None

        self.button_new_window = tk.Button(self, text = 'New Window', command = lambda : self.get_window(self))
        self.configure_grid()


    def configure_grid(self):
        '''Configures the Grid layout'''
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=(tk.N,tk.S,tk.E,tk.W))
        self.button_new_window.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx=5, pady=5)


    def get_window(self, parent):
        ''' If window exists, return it, else, create it'''
        self.new_window = self.new_window if self.new_window else Window(parent)
        return self.new_window




class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''Opens a new Window.
        @param parent -- tk.Widget that opens/reference this window
    '''
    def __init__ (self, parent : tk.Widget):

        # Stores reference to the Parent Widget, so you can set parent.new_window = None
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(master = parent.master)
        self.title('New Window')
        self.button_dummy = tk.Button(self, text = 'Do the thing', width = 25, command = lambda : print("Button pressed on window!"))
        self.button_close = tk.Button(self, text = 'Close', width = 25, command = self.close_me)
        self.configure_grid()


    def configure_grid(self):
        '''Grid'''
        self.button_dummy.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.button_close.grid(row = 2, column = 0)


    def close_me(self):
        '''Tkinter widgets are made of two parts. 1. The python Object and 2. The GUI Widget.
        The destroy() method gets rid of the widget part, but leaves the object in memory.
        
        To also destroy the object, you need to set all of its references count to ZERO on
        the Parent Widget that created the new Window, so the Garbage Collector can collect it.
        '''
        # Destroys the Widget
        self.destroy()
        # Decreasses the reference count on the Parent Widget so the Garbage Collector can destroy the python object
        self.parent.new_window = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    toolbar = Toolbar(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I don´t know if this: **.destroy()** and **re-instantiate** approach is more efficient than the **.withdraw()** and  **.deiconify()**. Maybe if you have a program that runs for long periods of time and opens a lot of windows it can be handy to avoid **stackoverflow** or heapoverflow.

It sure frees up the object reference from memory, but it has the additional cost of the re-instantiation, and that is processing time.

But as David J. Malan would say on CS50, “There´s always a tradeoff”.